# Function for prepared statements

Tags: php, prepared-statement

Is there a safe way use variables that are passed to a function (variables are not user defined) for table names in a prepared statement?

ie:

```
function select( $table )
{
    blah blah

    $stmt->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = ?" );

    blah blah
}
```

I have generated a function that has all available table names and if one of them matches $table, it returns the table name. I think it's called *hard-coding*. But I don't know is this is helping me. Basically i'm trying to create a function for insert/update/select using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compare `$table` to a known list of table names before using it in a query, that should be pretty safe.  The next-best thing would be to wrap the table name in tick marks and remove any tick marks in the incoming `$table` variable value.